# Не подсвечиваются вопросы с отслеживаемыми метками. Новые правила подсветки или временный баг?

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, игнорируемые-метки, отслеживаемые-метки

Перестали подсвечиваться вопросы по моим меткам.

[image: нет подсветки меток]

Это не список вопросов по конкретной метке, как видно по вопросу сверху. Однако те, которые отслеживаю, перестали выделяться цветом. И так для всех меток. Полностью белая лента.

Вопрос: с чем может быть связано, как фиксить?

Comment: Подтверждаю. Проблема есть. Игнорируемые метки не скрываются, а отслеживаемые не подсвечиваются.

Comment: [Проблема известная](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/366321/339911)

Comment: Фух... Починили :)

Comment: @UModeL, у вас визуально это видно? а то у меня пока без изменений вроде :(

Comment: @Andrew: да, всё работает, как раньше, т.е. как должно.

Comment: @UModeL, странно, у меня всё как было до починки, серое как неотслеживаемое. Чистил кэш, но не помогло :(

Comment: @Andrew: попробуйте изменить списки ваших меток (добавить или удалить какую-нибудь)

Comment: нет, без изменений, и добавлял и удалял, всё так же

Comment: @Andrew: тогда действительно странно, ибо у меня всё норм - как на ruSO, так и на enSO.

Comment: я даже в акк перезаходил) не помогло

Comment: Тоже самое, до сих пор не подсвечиваются

Comment: У меня подсвечивается. Может вам стоит попробовать в приватной вкладке проверить и/или почистить кеш/куки?

Comment: @AK, я попробовал куки почистить, перезайти, открывал в инкогнито, но пока всё глухо

Comment: @AK, появилось теперь, хотя ничего не делал) видать всё-таки было что-то от меня независящее)

Answer (score 2):

Проблема [исправлена](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/366345/339911). Клиентскую часть недостаточно хорошо тестируют.